# Is it correct to avoid using apostrophe in this situation?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, formal-language, apostrophe

I want to know whether it is possible to avoid using the apostrophe as suggested in the second option? or it should remain the same as it is in the first option?. Since it is the salute, I'm not sure it is correct to use apostrophe to point out that I am referring to the committee of the mentioned scholarship.

1.Dear members of the Agricultural Scholarship's Committee.

2.Dear members of the Agricultural Scholarship Committee.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the name of the committee, whatever it is. It is possible that name includes an apostrophe. It is also possible that the name does not include an apostrophe.

If I were naming a committee whose job was to award agricultural scholarships, I would not use an apostrophe.

If I was naming a committee whose job was to ensure exellent standards of Agricultural scholarship I would call it "The Committee of Agricultural Scholarship"

However I am not naming the committee.  Someone else has already done that, and even if they named it "wrong" you should still use their name.

If the name of the committee is not in English, then I question why you would write to them in English. The name of the committee is a good clue to the working language of the committee.

Generally it is a good idea to address the Chair of the committee, rather than the committee itself. So if possible use

> Dear Professor Smith,
>
> I am writing to you in your capacity as chair of the {name of committee}

Again use the actual name, and write in the working language of the committee, if possible.